# Difference in months between two dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two date columns ('dob', 'paymentDate'):

```
{'dob': {0: nan, 1: '10/16/1988', 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
'paymentDate': {0: '20120501',
1: '20100602',
2: '20110601',
3: '20120501',
4: '20110101'}}
```

I want to find the time delta in months between these. I am interested only in completed months (essentially the "floor" of the timedelta in months). In this particular case the result for the second row should be 259 (21 years, 7 months and 17 days = 21*12 + 7 = 259 months):

```
{'difference_in_months': {0: nan, 1: 259, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

How can I do this? I tried

```
from dateutil import relativedelta    
df_training_data['difference_in_months'] = relativedelta.relativedelta(df_training_data['paymentDate'], df_training_data['dob']).months
```

but I'm getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `to_datetime` and `to_period`

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_datetime,errors = 'coerce',axis=1)
df.paymentDate.dt.to_period('M')-df.dob.dt.to_period('M')-1
Out[95]: 
0    NaT
1    259
2    NaT
3    NaT
4    NaT
dtype: object
```